# Как убрать отступ при позиционировании элементов

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, frontend

Подозреваю что мое решение позиционировать эл-ты не самое лучшее, подскажите как будет правильнее.Необходимо убрать отступ который образовался на месте где изначально была картинка.

Код:

```css
.header-content p {
  position: relative;
  height: 550px;
  min-height: 550px;
  border: 6px solid yellow;
  border-bottom: none;
  padding: 60px 120px 0;
  z-index: 10;
  color: yellow;
  font-size: 18px;
}
img {
  position: relative;
    top: -370px;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="header-content">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
        <p>
          Еко- бренд SUN FOODS ™ — торгова марка сучасної інноваційної української компанії “СІНТЕКС”, яка спеціалізується на виробництві 100 % натуральних продуктах харчування
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <img class="responsive-img" src="img/about-img.jpg" alt="about-bg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="mouse-wrapper">
        <div class="mouse-icon">
          <div class="wheel">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[image: то что получилось]

Comment: `position: relative top: -370px z-index: 0`  поставьте для начала ";". Должно быть так: `position: relative; top: -370px; z-index: 0;`

Comment: это я с SASS копировал, исправил.Как грамотно позиционировать эти эл-ты, подскажите?

Comment: Виталий уже написал ответ, вполне отличное решение. Использовать не `top`, а `margin-top`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Замените `top` на `margin-top`.

```css
.header-content p {
  position: relative;
  height: 550px;
  min-height: 550px;
  border: 6px solid yellow;
  border-bottom: none;
  padding: 60px 120px 0;
  z-index: 10;
  color: yellow;
  font-size: 18px;
}
img {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: -370px;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="header-content">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10">
        <p>
          Еко- бренд SUN FOODS ™ — торгова марка сучасної інноваційної української компанії “СІНТЕКС”, яка спеціалізується на виробництві 100 % натуральних продуктах харчування
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12">
        <img class="responsive-img" src="http://pipsum.com/760x300.jpg" alt="about-bg">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="mouse-wrapper">
        <div class="mouse-icon">
          <div class="wheel">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```